# Customize ??? in which-func-mode

Tags: customize, which-function-mode

I have which-function-mode enabled and from time to time it shows ???. Is it possible to customize this to eg '∅'. I have tried to customize group "Which Func" but did not find something suiteable.

Also I do not completely understand when ??? is shown and what is means.

Comment: I would have tagged this question with which-function-mode but lack the reputation necessary to get this privilige.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

??? is displayed if `which-func-mode` (or `which-function-mode` in Emacs 25) can't determine the name of the current function. To customize it, modify the variable `which-func-unknown`, which is the "String to display in the mode line when current function is unknown."

```
(setq which-func-unknown "∅")
```

Its default value is "???".

Answer (score 2):

??? means `which-function-mode` can't find current function name.

Read code of `which-function-mode` you will find that `imenu` setup in your major mode hook provides function names used by other plugins like `which-function-mode`.

So the **real problem** is how to setup imenu in major mode hook.

Here is a simplified version of my setup for `js-mode`,

```
(setq javascript-common-imenu-regex-list
      '(("Controller" "[. \t]controller([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Controller" "[. \t]controllerAs:[ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Filter" "[. \t]filter([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("State" "[. \t]state[(:][ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Factory" "[. \t]factory([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Service" "[. \t]service([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Module" "[. \t]module( *['\"]\\([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\\)['\"], *\\[" 1)
        ("ngRoute" "[. \t]when(\\(['\"][a-zA-Z0-9_\/]+['\"]\\)" 1)
        ("Directive" "[. \t]directive([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Event" "[. \t]\$on([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Config" "[. \t]config([ \t]*function *( *\\([^\)]+\\)" 1)
        ("Config" "[. \t]config([ \t]*\\[ *['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("OnChange" "[ \t]*\$(['\"]\\([^'\"]*\\)['\"]).*\.change *( *function" 1)
        ("OnClick" "[ \t]*\$([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]*\\)['\"]).*\.click *( *function" 1)
        ("Watch" "[. \t]\$watch( *['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ("Function" "function[ \t]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_$.]+\\)[ \t]*(" 1)
        ("Function" "^[ \t]*\\([a-zA-Z0-9_$.]+\\)[ \t]*=[ \t]*function[ \t]*(" 1)
        ;; {{ es6 beginning
        ("Function" "^[ \t]*\\([A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]+\\)[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9, ]*) *\{ *$" 1) ;; es6 fn1 () { }
        ("Function" "^[ \t]*\\([A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]+\\)[ \t]*=[ \t]*(?[a-zA-Z0-9, ]*)?[ \t]*=>[ \t]*\{ *$" 1) ;; es6 fn1 = (e) => (var, var2) {
        ;; }}
        ("Task" "[. \t]task([ \t]*['\"]\\([^'\"]+\\)" 1)
        ))

;; js-mode imenu enhancement
;; @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863386/idomenu-not-working-in-javascript-mode
(defun mo-js-imenu-make-index ()
  (save-excursion
    (imenu--generic-function javascript-common-imenu-regex-list)))

(defun mo-js-mode-hook ()
  (setq imenu-create-index-function 'mo-js-imenu-make-index))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'mo-js-mode-hook)
```

My actual setup is more complicated (https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-javascript.el)

Some major modes provide advanced imenu utilities out of the box.

If there are multiple major modes for one programming language, the solution could be as simple as choosing a better major mode.

For example, both js-mode and js2-mode supports javascript, but js2-mode provides better imenu utilities. If you use js2-mode for javascript code, your `which-function-mode` works with much less manual imenu setup code.

My article http://blog.binchen.org/posts/why-emacs-is-better-editor.html discuss the technical details on hacking js2-mode imenu code if you are still not satisfied with js2-mode's default imenu setup.

The reason you need hacking is that some major modes will provide their own imenu framework. For example, in `web-mode` you need change `web-mode-imenu-regexp-list` instead of standard imenu variables.

Grep my emacs configuration at https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/tree/master/lisp , you will find many samples on imenu setup.

Comment: Very extensive answer. It really inspires me to go more into depth about imenu and how it works! Thank you.